# How to get custom element values

Tags: jquery, html

This must have come by more then once, but I don't know how to name this and I need the value of it. How?

```
<div data-type="value i need"></div>
```

I see things like data-type (or another custom name) everywhere, but I can't name it or get the value in jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called HTML 5 data attributes.

Give your element an id or class and then call `$("#id").data("type")` or `$("#id").attr("data-type")` to access the value.

Check out the working example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNSz/).